# How do I use Pentaho spoon to push data from MySQL database to facebook webpage

Tags: json, rest, api, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

1) I have already made transformation mapping for getting data from specific MySQL (Table Input) and convert it as Text File output.

2) Also I have created a facebook developer account page and  trying to figure out how the Facebook API works to push data from MYsql to facebook.

3) would appreciate if transformation mapping can be provided. Also I would not like to use XML, instead I would like to use JSON.

Already the msql table is converted to csv file, but I am not sure how to post the csv file to facebook or is there a way to connect mysql table to facebook directly. Please share your ideas or transformation mapping. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would Assuemm you are familiar with Facebook Development API to do all actions like post,get and so on.

You have a step called "REST CLIENT STEP" in Pentaho.

you will have an API url to post the data that you want from mySQL. There several methods GET PUT POST DELETE

Also set the Application Format to Json (XML,JSON etc).

I used to read data from FB using REST Client by using GET Method. Work around.

Comment: my tansformation looks like Table input (MySQL table)-->Text File output(storing it to my local drive)-->JSON output(to convert output to JSON parameters) and the final step Rest Client ( I am putting post entering url, client id and field names..etc.). I am able to get variables till json output but for some reason Rest client not able to read the field names url). I am not sure how the parameters look like in Rest Client.to post the data.